# Battery Limiter cannot start

Tags: windows, laptop, battery, .net-framework

I am a using a Battery Limiter app by robotonfire (https://www.robotonfire.com/bl/).
It was working good for few weeks and suddenly came this error
"
ERROR: Battery Limiter cannot start. The invocation of the constructor on type 'BatteryLimiter.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception
"

Reinstalling and restarting doesn't help, any solution is appreciated.

Comment: Only the original developer can help you with this.

Comment: Quality computer manufacturers provide battery charge threshold management software that is integrated with the computer BIOS. I would not trust the add-on devices.

Comment: This program is *awful*. Please do not use it. It will greatly reduce your battery life. When your laptop is fully charged, it neither charges nor discharges. When you disconnect your laptop before it's fully charged, it begins discharging immediately. Your battery only has limited capacity to discharge and charge. By discharging it when you do not need to, you will run through this limited capacity about 20-30% faster. This is *much* more severe than the 2% to 5% life increase from reducing charging stress. This program is *DUMB*.

Comment: Note that this is not even remotely comparable to what rational charge limiting programs do. Rational charge limiting programs put the battery into a state where it neither charges nor discharges *earlier* and for *longer*. This program does the very opposite of that by trying to get you to *never* put the battery in that state!

Answer (score 0):

Got a fix from robotonfire twitter handle,
https://twitter.com/robotonfire_com/status/1362145693973032962

"Sorry for the late reply, but here goes. Your problem is probably corrupt user settings, happens sometimes after windows updates or something. To fix it, open this path C:\Users%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local, find the http://robotonfire.com folder and delete it. This should fix it"

This fixed my problem.